# Wordpress/Woocommerce/PHP Ordering Products - Sale | In_Stock | Out_stock

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

This is running on a Wordpress/Woocommerce site within the functions.php file.
Currently, I have it ordering - In_stock | Out_stock but I'm not sure what I have to add in order for products on sale to be at the top of each shop page. How and Where would I able to find what variables can be used within the functions.php file.

```
    class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Check if WooCommerce is active
        if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
            add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
        }
    }

    public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        // only change query on WooCommerce loops
        if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
            $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
            $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
        }
        return $posts_clauses;
    }
}



new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```